# Adaptive cards back button

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I want to have a very simple back button on my sub dialogs. 
I use Adaptive Cards, on every card I have a back button.
Every dialog has it's context.done() 
The problem is that it's returning back to the main dialog but because it's holding only value and not text and then the StartAsync of the main dialog is waiting for input instead of reloading the main screen by moving with the context.wait

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using C# or Node.js? And what channel is this bot for?